Get Month to date, Year to date, Quarter to date quantities in Redshift
I have three columns - product name ie bn, date of product recieved and quantity_recieved columns,
I want to roll up the quantity recieved by month to date, year to date and quarter to date column.
How can I do this in redshift ?
I created the below syntax, but it gives me error.
SELECT bn,
  SUM(quantity_received) OVER (
     PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', latest__delivery_date),
                  DATE_TRUNC('year', latest_delivery_date),
                  isbn
     ORDER BY latest_vendor_delivery_date 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS month_to_date
FROM a 

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

but it gives me error - add to question error message and error point?
